# How to decrease the number of sheets in a workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

In a new Microsoft Excel workbook (2010) I have three sheets by default. Suppose that I suddenly press the *Insert worksheet button* next to the *Sheet3*, so the forth sheet will become added to the list of the sheets. But I like to have only three sheets, that is, I want to revert the situation to its previous state. I know how to hide or delete that sheet and also close the workbook without saving the changes. But I don't want them. I like to undo (which of course undo/ctrl+z doesn't work for this case) the work to have the before list of sheets. Is there a way?

Comment: Use Libreoffice - then ctrl+Z will work.

Comment: Do you mean that every time you add a new sheet, you want the oldest sheet to be automatically deleted, so the number of sheets is always kept to three?

Comment: @Garrulinae: No I want to know whether is there any way to return the before circumstances (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3). Not automatically deleting or like this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is easily answered by a Google search. Too trivial.

Comment: Frankly, asking a question to which you know there are several possible answers and then excluding them all because "I don't want to do it in any of the normal ways anyone would do that" does not make this a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot 'undo' creating a worksheet in Excel. You will have to delete it.

If you don't want to use your mouse, you can use the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>L</kbd> (Alt+E leads to 'Edit' and L to delete) to delete the current worksheet, which will be the one you just inserted if you accidentally did so.

Comment: OK Jerry. The case I was looking for was that comment of you, _You cannot 'undo' creating a worksheet in Excel. You will have to delete it._, not the rest. Anyway I think it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: But also bear in mind if there is only one way of undoing it, it's closing that Excel file without saving the changes.

Comment: @abbasi I wouldn't call that undoing, I would call that not saving changes :) Because you would also lose anything you did between your last save and the closing of the workbook. It might be possible, but I would think that you will need to write a script for that, certainly not my field of expertise :(

Comment: "I think it's possible" - why on earth would you think that? Just because you _wish_ it was true?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the tab for the sheet you want to delete. There is a menu item to delete the sheet.

Really though, a Google search would have shown you this, not a good question for SuperUser.

Comment: I think you haven't read my question properly. If you would look at it correctly I SAID "I don't want them.". Deleting a sheet is one the simplest works on Excel. I asked something else.

Comment: Perhaps because the question is a little odd. if you accidentally add a sheet, delete it again. If you really want to go to town, write a macro that overloads the SAVE function and deletes any empty sheets before saving the workbook. Rather serious overkill though just to cope with an occasional slip of the finger.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to File and then Options and look in the General section of options you'll find a heading for "When creating new workbooks" that has a selection for "Include this many sheets" which you can set to 1. Once this is set new workbooks will open with only a single worksheet.

[image]

Comment: Really I'm in doubt was I writing this question here in English language or in Chines language!

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). 讲清楚帮助别人明白你说什么。

Comment: It's because it is such a strange question I think.